# How can we read a file from a URL and insert it line by line into MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, file, url, meteor

I have a text file in server which need to be retrieved and the content of that file should be inserted line by line as new document in MongoDB.

For example, my text file in URL "http://example.com/sample.txt" be:

#### sample.txt

```
 abcdefg
 hijklmn
 opqrstu
 vwxyz
```

I want to insert "abcdefg" as one entry into my collection and the rest as followed in same manner. My database should look like:

```
db.test.find().pretty()
  {"_id":sdjcvajsvjhdb36,"name":"abcdefg"},
  {"_id":chvbjedfve6f7v,"name":"hijklmn"}
  {"_id":tuhgiy837842,"name":"opqrstu"}
  {"_id":chw67t8533fif3,"name":"vwxyz"}
```

What I have coded will retrieve the files data and place "\n" between the data and inserts as single entry in the database.

```
    var file="http://example.com/sample.txt"
    var result=HTTP.call('GET',file, { auth:"test:test"});
    console.log(result.content);
    productImage.insert({"image":result.content});
```

The entry in the collection will be:

```
{ "_id" : "cqcgPTEb62ay8L7Gq", "name" : "abcdefg\nhijklmn\nopqrstu\nuvwxyz" }
```

I'm using the above code inside the /meteorApp/server/method.js. How do I achieve this goal? And is there any alternate method by which we can directly query the MongoDB database and insert in that format?

Comment: what does ```console.log(result.content);``` show?

Comment: `abcdefg
     hijklmn
     opqrstu
     vwxyz`   in the same format the file is represent. as shown in my sample.txt.

Comment: if it's simple text, then just use ```.split()``` to convert the string into an array. Then iterate through the array and insert each element into the db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by your comment,

`result.content` contains: `"abcdefg\nhijklmn\nopqrstu\nuvwxyz"`

**Solution:**

1. Split the string at "\n"
2. For each element, insert to db.

.

```
    var fileArray = result.content.split("\n"); // ["abcdefg","hijklmn","opqrstu","uvwxyz"] 

    fileArray.pop(); // removes the trailing "" element 


    fileArray.forEach(function (element){
         productImage.insert({"image":element});
    });
```

Comment: The data is getting stored as i expected, thank you @blueren. But one extra null value is also getting added into DB, how can we avoid that?

Comment: { "_id" : "psF56hxRTr2nmLL6d", "image" : "" } this is the last entry after all the data is inserted.

Comment: Observe your text file. The very last line will also have a ```\n```. When you split the string, check the ```fileArray``` variable. it will also contain an empty string ```""```. You can just drop that from the array and proceed. You  can use ```.pop()``` to get the job done. I've updated my answer.

Comment: How can i run the above code at the startup and only once in meteor server side?@blueren

Comment: @Snkini - Well that is almost entirely a whole new question. If you want to, you could throw the above code into ```Meteor.startup()``` and insert into the db only when one of the images don't already exist in the db. Whatever is in the startup will always run each time the app reloads.

Comment: Inserting `Meteor.startup()` in server side right?. if so which one is loaded first the client side or server side?

Comment: Yes, you will need to put it in the server side. Regarding your second question.. I'm not sure, though I'd think it's the server that loads first and then 'serves' data to the client.